# How to do 'svn checkout URL' using exec?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to checkout Joe English's tile-extras from Github using svn using a Tcl script.

The required command is

```
svn checkout https://github.com/jenglish/tile-extras.git path
```

I have some code that boils down to

```
exec C:/cygwin64/bin/svn.exe checkout                \
     https://github.com/jenglish/tile-extras.git C:/cygwin64/tmp/TCL61416]
```

which fails with the message

```
couldn't execute "C:\cygwin64\bin\svn.exe checkout
         https:\github.com\jenglish\tile-extras.git 
    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61416": No error
```

Pasting the command quoted in the error message into a Windows Command Prompt window, I see

```
svn: E125002: 'https:\github.com\jenglish\tile-extras.git' does not appear to be a URL
```

So, the problem seems to be that `exec` converts Tcl-style paths to Unix-style a little over-enthusiastically. Is there any way I can prevent it from converting `https://github.com/jenglish...` to `https:\github.com\jenglish...`?

For information, I'm running on Windows 10, with cygwin (setup version 2.889 (64 bit)), svn 1.9.7 and tcl version 8.6.7 (via ActiveTcl 8.6.7.0).

**UPDATE**

Here is my actual code, which I'm only slightly embarrassed by:

```
# svn wrapper proposed by Donal Fellows at
# http://stackoverflow/questions/49224268

proc svn {args} {
    exec {*}[auto_execok svn] {*}$args <@stdin >@stdout }

# Checkout from github to a temporary repository

set repository https://github.com/jenglish/tile-extras.git set
svnImage [auto_execok svn]

set fil [file tempfile tempfnm] close $fil file delete $tempfnm

set tempRepo [file rootname $tempfnm] puts stdout tempRepo:\ $tempRepo
file mkdir $tempRepo

set svnCmd [list svn checkout $repository [file nativename $tempRepo]]
puts stdout svnCmd:\ $svnCmd eval $svnCmd

# Determine the tile-extras sources

set sourceFiles {keynav.tcl icons.tcl}
set targets [file nativename [file join $tempRepo trunk *.tcl]]
foreach filnam [split [svn ls $targets] \n] {
    if {[string match *.tcl $filnam] && [lsearch $sourceFiles $filnam] < 0}  {
        lappend sourceFiles $filnam
    }
 }
```

And here is the result

```
$ tclsh foo.tcl
tempRepo: C:/cygwin64/tmp/TCL61838
svnCmd: svn checkout
https://github.com/jenglish/tile-extras.git {C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838}
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/branches
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/README.md
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/dialog.tcl
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/doc
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/doc/dialog.n
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/doc/keynav.n
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/icons.tcl
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/keynav.tcl
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/license.terms
A    C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838/trunk/pkgIndex.tcl
Checked out revision 7.
svn: E155007: '/home/alan/C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61838\trunk\*.tcl' is not a working copy
    while executing "exec {*}[auto_execok svn] {*}$args <@stdin >@stdout"
    (procedure "svn" line 2)
    invoked from within "svn ls $targets"
    invoked from within "split [svn ls $targets] \n"
    invoked from within "foreach filnam [split [svn ls $targets] \n] {
    if {[string match *.tcl $filnam] && [lsearch $sourceFiles $filnam] < 0} {
        lappend sourceFiles $filn..."
    (file "foo.tcl" line 30)
$ ls /tmp/TCL61838/
$
```

The directory `/tmp/TCL61838` is empty, so it seems the `svn checkout` command didn't complete completely happily. I also see an unpleasant mixture of forward slashes and backslashes being reported by `svn`.

Thanks in advance for any more help.

Comment: Wait, what? Since when can you clone a Git repository using SVN?

Comment: And why do you need Tcl for that?

Comment: Answering the two questions above in the order asked - I've no idea, but, from the Github help at https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/, "You can also use a Subversion client to access any repository on GitHub". I don't _need_ Tcl. I wish to  concatenate the various sources into a single file for reasons that I no longer remember. I have a codebase, built up over ten years, relying on that single file which is large enough that I wish to continue to use the technique.

Comment: Does it work when you enclose the URL in braces `{}`?

Comment: That's not so easy to do; I actually have both the URL and the `exec` command in variables and I haven't been immediately able to generate something with exactly one pair of braces around the URL. I'm writing the command to the screen so am confident that it is exactly as appears above.

Comment: I see a stray close bracket: are you actually doing `exec [list svn url dir]`? You say your code "boils down" to this. We need to see the actual soup

Comment: @glenn jackman I'm not sure where the stray `]` has come from. I've gone with Donal's suggestion below of the `proc svn` wrapper and no longer have the code from last night. I understand the need to see "the actual soup" but I'm embarrassed to share it at present :-(

Comment: I get that. However when you ask about little bits of you real problem you get into [the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Agreed. However, I'm also prone to `tl;dr` syndrome and seem to have swung too far the other way this time.

Answer (score 2):

Given the error message, it looks like you're getting word boundaries wrong in the code that you've not shown us; while you might believe the code “boils down to” to that `exec`, it's not *actually* done that. Also, you've flipped the slashes in the URL which won't work, but that's probably a side-effect of something else.

Alas, I can't quite guess how to fix things for you. There's just too many options. I provide a suggestion below, but there's no telling for sure whether it will work out.

### Diagnosis Methodology

The evidence for why I believe that the problem is what I say? This interactive session log (on OSX, but the generic behaviour should be the same):

```
% exec cat asdkfajh
cat: asdkfajh: No such file or directory
% exec "cat akjsdhfdkj"
couldn't execute "cat akjsdhfdkj": no such file or directory
% exec "cat aksdjhfkdf" skdjfghd
couldn't execute "cat aksdjhfkdf": no such file or directory
```

The first case shows an error from an external program. The second case shows an error due to no-such-program. The third case shows that *arguments are not reported* when erroring due to to no-such-program.

This lets me conclude that both `C:\cygwin64\bin\svn.exe` and its arguments (`checkout`, `https:\github.com\jenglish\tile-extras.git` and `C:\cygwin64\tmp\TCL61416`) were *actually* passed as a single argument to `exec`, a fairly common error, and that the problems lie in the preparatory code. You don't show us the preparatory code, so we can't truly fix things but we can make suggestions that address the common problems.

### Suggested Approach

A good way to reduce these errors is to write a small wrapper procedure:

```
proc svn {args} {
    # I add in the I/O redirections so svn can ask for a password
    exec {*}[auto_execok svn] {*}$args <@stdin >@stdout
}
```

This would let you write your call to svn as:

```
svn checkout $theURL [file nativename $theDirectory]
```

and it would probably Just Work™. Also note that *only* the directory name goes through `file nativename`; the URL does not. (We could embed the call to `file nativename` in the procedure if we were making a specialised procedure to do checkouts, but there's too much variation in the full svn program to let us do that. The caller — you — has to deal with it.)

Comment: Thanks Donal. I've managed to get past my error by using your `svn` proc. What with increasingly desperate attempts to fix the problem by making "voodoo" changes and huge amounts of trace together with `gets stdin` to allow me to investigate what was happening on the disk while the program was running, my original code was in too much of a mess to allow me to post it. I will say, that I was never passing the URL through `file nativename`. I _was_ assuming that `auto_execok` returned a single word and _wasn't_ passing the local filename through `file nativename`.